# Inserting into the database using php using queries to fill the values part and getting SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql

```
require 'db_config.php';

$filename = "truck_a.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

fclose($fp);
list($name, $lat, $lon) = explode(',', $content); 

try {

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   $loc = 'In-Transit';
   $q3a = $db-> query("INSERT INTO Truck1_data id = ((select max(id) from Truck1_data) +1), Location = '".$loc."') where (select location from Truck1_data where id = max(id)) <> '".$loc."') and (select location from Truck1_data where id = max(id)) <>'In-Transit' ");  


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: And what is the full error?

Comment: Insert have not where condition  .. could be you need  update

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = ((select max(id) from Truck1_data) +1), Location = 'In-Transit') where (sel' at line 1" ---- This is the complete error.

Comment: No equals sign in an Insert query

Comment: scaisEgde - I want to insert only when those conditions are met. How do I change the query then?

Comment: aynber - Can we use the syntax of values here, because when i used values syntax with update it showed an error so i had to change it.

Comment: @AnandSaran the parenthesises don't even match up...

Comment: you need  update  ... but your code is full of others  error  .. you must rethink your code  .. and take a deep  study in SQL

Comment: Please state your question clearly, don't just copypaste code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the help from others and searching for some solutions.I have changed the coloumn id to auto increment. I have got an answer for my question, hopefully helps someone like me.

try {

```
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   $loc = 'In-Transit';

   $q3aa = $db->query("select Location from Truck1_data where id = (select max(id) from Truck1_data)"); 
   $loctn = $q3ab->fetchAll();

   if(!strcmp($loc,$loctn)) {
   $q3a = $db-> query("INSERT INTO Truck1_data SET Location=('".$loc."') ");   
   }


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put a `SET` between `Truck1_data` and `id`  though I believe the rest of your code will bomb out as well

Comment: take a better  llok at the OP query